# Post To facebook wall from Meteor

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor

I use meteor's `accounts-ui` with the `accounts-facebook` package as a login in for my app. From this login I receive the users facebook access token which should give me the ability to post to their facebook wall. However when I try to post an image I get a `permission error`. I have also noticed that when a user logs in at the bottom of the facebook logged in modal it has a dialog that says something like `this app cannot post to your profile`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read carefully the docs of http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithexternalservice, it states that you can configure it to pass a "requestPermissions" option, you need to use this to explicitly request the permission to post on user behalf. (you will find the permission name in facebook developers docs, not Meteor).

Comment: @simenunt I am definitely using "requestPermissions". Could you post a quick example of that? Im not quite sure on how to implement it.